# Dockerized Node JS application not accessible from host machine

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have Node JS application

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
  services:  
    app:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      command: 'yarn nuxt'
      ports:
       - 3000:3000
      volumes:
       - '.:/app'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:15

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl

RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn

WORKDIR /app
```

After running `$ docker-compose up -d` application starts and inside container it's accessible

```
$ docker-compose exec admin sh -c 'curl -i localhost:3000'
// 200 OK
```

But outside of container it's doesnt work. For example in chrome `ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED`

Comment: In your application code, how do you set up the listener?  If you explicitly bind to `127.0.0.1` the process will be unreachable from outside its container with pretty much exactly these symptoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to `app` service solves problem in **docker-compose.yml**

```
environment:
    HOST: 0.0.0.0
```

Thanks to Marc Mintel article [Development setup with Nuxt, Node and Docker](https://medium.com/i22digital/development-setup-with-nuxt-node-and-docker-b008a241c11d#fb37)

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add

```
published: 3000
```

you can read more here - https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/